# Bitwise operation in character

Tags: c, char, bit

I am curious about a behavior of bit-wise operator of C on Character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 108;
    x = x<<1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    char y = 108;
    y = y<<1;
    printf("%d", y);
    //printf("%d", y<<1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, if I pass like this, y = y<<1, it's output was *-40* and when I print it directly like,

> printf("%d", y<<1);

it's output was *216*.

How I can simulate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is really no `<<` operation on `char` types - the operands of `<<` are promoted to (at least) `int` types, and the result is, similarly, an `int`.

So, when you do `y = y << 1`, you are truncating the `int` result of the operation to a (signed) `char`, which leaves the most significant bit (the *sign bit*) set, so it is interpreted as a negative value.

However, when you pass `y << 1` *directly* to `printf`, the resulting `int` is left unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

`y<<1` produces an `int`. To get -40, you were implicitly casting it to a `char`. In your `printf` case, you'll need to do the cast explicitly: `(char)(y<<1)`

Comment: Note: It might behave differently on a different compiler, or with different compiler flags; `char` has implementation-defined signedness, so `-40` implies it's `signed` on that implementation (and I *think* the truncation from `int` back to `char` is technically undefined signed overflow, but won't swear to that; most systems are two's complement and behave as observed), but it could just as easily be `216` on another system where it's `unsigned`. Basically, never use plain `char` for math that produces results outside the range [0, 128).

Comment: `and I think the truncation from int back to char is technically undefined signed overflow` No worries, implementation defined.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, All true, but those are problems that apply to the code the OP asked to replicate. I showed how to replicate the code, problems and all.

Comment: @ikegami: I wasn't criticizing, just adding the note for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Excellent, just non-portable, no nasal demons. :-)

Comment: Yup, I got that. Also for the benefit of the OP :)